# C source file is not opening in notepad++

Tags: 16.04, wine

I have installed Notepad++ using wine in Ubuntu 16.4 LTS. And set Notepad++ as a default editor for .c file using Ubuntu Tweak.

But whenever I want to open any .c file, the Notepad++ is opening with blank page. The .c file is not opening.

Please guide me how to solve this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why use Wine for this? Just about every text editor for Ubuntu has syntax highlighting.

Comment: To whoever has voted to close this as not being about Ubuntu: ***What?***

Comment: @EliahKagan Likly, they saw notepad++ and jumped on it, I see this all the time in review recently

Comment: Mark Kirby I know there are so many editors are present but I want Notepad++,  you have any solution?

Comment: @EliahKagan can you solve this? I don't want to know any kind of others stuffs.

Comment: What wine version are you using? It works perfectly for me. [image](https://imgur.com/a/hZWg6)

Comment: Wine issues can be hard to diagnose, that is why I was going to offer alternitives but if that is the one you wabt, that is fine. Most likly cause is a wrong Wine prefix, have you tried removing it and then installing it with play on linux? Play on linux will automatically set the correct prefix `sudo apt install playonlinux`

Comment: @Sirjajus Salekin I am using Wine 1.6.2

Comment: @SirajusSalekin I can open .c file by manually. But when I want to open a pre written .c file using duble click, it opens only a blank document rather than that file.

Comment: not answer .I suggest you to use vim or vs code instead of notepad++

Comment: Try latest wine, 1.6.2 version is terribly ancient. ATM the latest version is wine-2.19